# How to filter with any field values in Object in Firebase console?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have tried to filter the field from the object from the Firestore console but there is no option to filter that with the object.
If we have a list then we have the option with array-contains in Add Condition.

For Ex: I need to filter with name field from object,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can put the fully qualified field name in the filter field. So in this case, you'd use `TempObj.name` to get the filtering you want.

[image: firestore filter example]